# Difference between REST and WebServices

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, soap

What is difference between REST and WebService (SOAP), I looked at the facebook api, they use HTTP headers and some parameters (probably xml or non) and return result in xml, where else SOAP does exactly same, HTTP headers + xml parameters and returns headers + xml.

REST also requires some authenticated token where else SOAP uses http session which is exactly same token used for auth and other information. All I can see that SOAP is little advanced version of REST?

Or are there any other performance considerations? Reading about REST just talks very high level of client server communication but even SOAP does exactly same. Can anyone point me where it can define correct boundry of REST and SOAP.

We use lot of SOAP transparently in .net, however I just want to know is it really worth paying attension to REST where currently everything is running outstandingly smooth.

I know REST is an architecture and SOAP is a protocol but my question is in detail that is currently the ASP.NET WebService implementation of SOAP has REST architecture?

Comment: There are potential duplicates of this - REST vs SOAP seems to be a common question (via @John Saunders, good point but rolled back because the comment was made in an edit). While the topic is duplicated I think this question will come up on searches where the others will not, so the question should stay open.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

SOAP is a protocol for sending/receiving data over HTTP as XML.

A typical WebService will be a few methods an WSDL that describes how to call it. There's no real convention for how these should be structured, so you always need lots of API documentation.

Typically this will be something like (for ASP.NET):

- HTTP `POST` to *mysite.com/products.asmx/ListAllProducts* - returns XML list of products
- HTTP `POST` to *mysite.com/products.asmx/GetProduct* - returns XML for product based on SOAP XML in the posted content
- HTTP `POST` to *mysite.com/products.asmx/UpdateProduct* - changes product based on SOAP XML in the posted content

REST is more of a convention for structuring all of your methods:

- HTTP `GET` from *mysite.com/products* - returns XML or JSON listing all products
- HTTP `GET` from *mysite.com/products/14* - returns XML or JSON for product 14
- HTTP `POST` to *mysite.com/products/14* - changes product 14 to what you post in the HTML form.
- HTTP `DELETE` to *mysite.com/products/14* - removes product 14
- HTTP `PUT` to *mysite.com/products* - adds a new product

So REST works more like you'd expect browser URLs to. In that way it's more natural and as a convention is much easier to understand. All REST APIs work in a similar way, so you don't spend as long learning the quirks of each system.

Comment: Ok so REST does everything purely on HTTP where else Web Service does purely on SOAP, on Web Service you need little additional tools to SOAP Marshelling right? Thank you.

Comment: About DELETE and PUT, since REST is mostly for machines talking to each other, not having access to those verbs from a browser is maybe not that critical.

I think it's pretty important to state the focus on verbs for REST, while SOAP puts the actual commands into the request, instead of the type of the request.

Comment: @vs - good point. @Akash Kava - not quite, as SOAP is over HTTP too. You can call either mechanism in Javascript from a simple web page. The important thing about REST is using the convention of HTTP verbs (GET, POST, etc) rather than calling method names read from the WSDL

Comment: The constraint of using a uniform interface is only one aspect of REST.  You also need conform to "self descriptive messages", the "Hypermedia as the engine of application constraint", statelessness on the server.  Without these you are not doing REST, because without adhering to these constraints you will not get the benefits characteristics of a RESTful system.

Comment: @vs Yes, REST is ideal for a "client application" to talk to a "server application".  It is not really the best choice for a "server application" to talk to a "server application".  The interactions of a RESTful interface are best when driven by a human being through a "client-application".

Comment: i think using REST you can not send large amount of data(like data of sign up page) from client to server. So, in this case web service is helpful.

Comment: @user609239 that's incorrect - both REST and SOAP work over HTTP, and in either case the maximum amount of data that you can send is a property of your web server configuration. Also why would your sign-up page need a large amount of data? Surely sign-up is just a few fields, maybe even a profile image?

Comment: Small correction for: "SOAP is a protocol for sending/receiving data over HTTP as XML."; SOAP can be over any transport protocols such HTTP, FTP, STMP, JMS etc.

Comment: @ShiDoiSi already touched on this but I don't feel it was clear enough for new-comers.  To be clear, REST is a common solution for client-server web apps and a user using a web-app via a browser can interact with a RESTful service; they just can't do it directly.  It's typically done by tying a JavaScript function to a some HTML-element and that JavaScript in turn calls the RESTful service (ie: PUT, DELETE, etc).  This is commonly done using jQuery but there are certainly plenty of other ways to do that.

Comment: @Keith if REST can work over HTTP then we can very well do a GET (as in GET HTTP verb) for SOAP based ws?

Comment: @AniketThakur yes, you can sometimes, depending on configuration and such, but the question would be why? Most WSDL code generators built all POST methods - I'm not sure what the benefit would be of doing a GET if the WSDL defines what the function does.

Answer (score 13):

For me a service implemented using a RESTful approach wins over one that uses SOAP or RPC in terms of its accessibility. In a relatively closed system where tooling is available to generate stubs and ties based on a WSDL, this is not terribly important. However, if you want to create services that are accessible and available to a wide range of clients, then the uniformity of REST services and ease with which they can be consumed is a big plus i.e. you don't need a heavy RPC stack, just the ability to make HTTP requests.

Not sure this totally answers your question, but if, as you say, you have a system that works based on SOAP (and you control the client and server) then I don't see any reason to change. Besides, some services will naturally lend themselves more to RPC based access, in which case a SOAP interface will be more appropriate.

In terms of performance, one or more layers would effectively be removed from the client and server technology stacks if you don't use SOAP, so all other things being equal, a service which exposes a RESTful interface will win there.