# What is REST service?

Tags: asp.net

What is REST service and how it is different from web service. thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Difference between REST and WebServices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443160/difference-between-rest-and-webservices)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Infact you cannot compare between REST & Web Service, as Web service/ WCF service makes use of REST. For details please check below links

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-137171.html

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer

Answer (score 4):

In a nutshell, a REST service is focussed around resources. A SOAP service is typically focussed around operations.

Note that both REST and SOAP services are considered to be web services if they are operating over HTTP, even though different protocols are used.

[See here for more info.](http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest)

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to compare a [RESTful web service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer#RESTful_web_services) with other web services. Check the link...

Answer (score 2):

It's a way of designing a web service.

[Representational State Transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer)

Answer (score 2):

it was asked before...
[Difference between REST and WebServices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1443160/difference-between-rest-and-webservices)

another one.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/

Answer (score 2):

http://www.xfront.com/REST-Web-Services.html

http://www.ajaxonomy.com/2008/xml/web-services-part-1-soap-vs-rest